# GWT / Eclipse, waiting for launch urls... WHY?

Tags: eclipse, gwt

Every time I start my GWT app in Eclipse, there is a message that says "Waiting for launch URLs", and then a random wait. It's as if it talks to a Google site informing it that I'm running a GWT app. Or perhaps an XML doc is fetching a template of sorts.

What the heck is it doing? My internet connection sucks and the wait is sometimes over 10 seconds. Can I make it stop doing this and not have it "wait" for whatever it's "waiting" for?

Answer (score 1):

GWT does check for to see if there's an updated version available, but that's done in a separate thread.

Wild guess: Do you experience delays if your machine is completely disconnected from a network?  It smells a little like a DNS timeout, since generating the launch URL involves asking for the local machine's hostname.  If your system's name resolver were misconfigured, that could explain why there's an initial delay before a negative result is cached locally.

Comment: Interesting! Is there maybe an option to turn off the hostname lookup? If that speeds up things, I would usually prefer the launch URL to be based on the bindAddress (or 127.0.0.1 in case of bindAddress==0.0.0.0)

Comment: Adding -logLevel TRACE might help narrow down the problem.  One thing the startupUrls seems to block on is for the Code Server listener to startup. (See DevModeBase.setStartupUrls())